# Which databases can create function-based indexes?

Tags: database, indexing

I know, that this type of indexes exist in Oracle. Old versions on MySQL can not create function-based indexes (thanks, google). And new versions? How about PostgreSQL, SQL Server etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know inner details of oracle's, but postgres can create index on expression, which can be a function, [from](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-createindex.html) :

> An index field can be an expression
>   computed from the values of one or
>   more columns of the table row. This
>   feature can be used to obtain fast
>   access to data based on some
>   transformation of the basic data. For
>   example, an index computed on
>   upper(col) would allow the clause
>   WHERE upper(col) = 'JIM' to use an
>   index.

EDIT:
MySQL seems to still be forging this, see [virtual columns](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_virtual_columns_preview) for details. Also some discussions [here](http://forge.mysql.com/worklog/task.php?id=1075). Don't seem very active.

DB2 does [it](http://ibmsystemsmag.blogs.com/db2utor/2007/11/db2-9-index-wit.html).

MS SQL can not do it, but using computed columns you can have similar effects; see [discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/670fd1c5-5990-4ab4-96d6-fe72a33b7394).

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL can create indexes on expressions including functions: [Indexes on Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/indexes-expressional.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could emulate function based indexes if your database supports insert and update triggers.

Add a column that will contain the function values and add index for that column. Then have your triggers to update column containing function values. Your queries have to change, replace `function(params)` with `function_col`.